# How does one individually extract elements from a tensor?

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow

Let us assume that I have a tensor in tensorflow with 2 elements.

How do I extract these individual elements and perform calculations on them?

```
def multiplication(a):
    return a[0]*a[1]

def main():
    sess=tf.Session
    a=tf.constant([[2,3]])
    answer= multiplication(a)
    print(sess.run(answer))
    #answer should be 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First recognize that your input array has shape (1,2), so `a[0]*a[1]` will not work.

Following is the code that is working for me-

```py
def mul(a):
    return a[0][0]*a[0][1]

a = tf.constant([[2,3]])
b = tf.contrib.eager.py_func(func = mul, inp=[a], Tout = tf.int32)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(b)
```

If you want to pass custom functions, check this link- https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function